# Cannot Loop Nested Json, get error (TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str)

Tags: python

So I have looked everywhere, and have not found a solution.

```
import urllib2
import json

shabad = raw_input('Shabad Number: ')
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
igurbani_api =  urllib2.Request('https://lab.sarabveer.me/igurbani-api/?&mode=2&shabadNo=' + shabad + '&format=json', headers = hdr)
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(igurbani_api)
data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['gurbani']['shabad']:
    print item['Gurmukhi']
```

When I run this I get error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Here is an example of what the actual JSON Looks like: [EXAMPLE](https://lab.sarabveer.me/igurbani-api/index.hh?&mode=2&shabadNo=504&format=json)

I Basically need to Loop the JSON and display every `Gurmukhi` variable.

Comment: I believe it is because you are attempting to access a list. Your JSON is like {'string': [{'string'...}]...} it contains a list

Comment: data['gurbani'] returns a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for d in data['gurbani']:
    print d['shabad']['Gurmukhi']
```

This is because `data['gurbani']` returns a list

Comment: it worked! wow, i tried this before and it didnt, well thats programming

Answer (score 1):

`data['gurbani']` is a list... as such

`data['gurbani']["shabad"]` is an error

try

`for item in data['gurbani'][0]["shabad"]`

or really **probably**

```
for translation in data['gurbani']:
    print translation["shabad"]["Gurmukhi"]
```

Comment: Returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: thats a different error at a different place ...  but i fixed it for you in my second example anyway